# C++ raise method

Tags: c++

I am trying to do raise method in my constructor. But i get link error on metho create in SomeMatrix. In UsualMatrix and ThinMatrix constructors differents only by type of vector.

```
class SomeMatrix: public IMatrix
{

public:
    virtual IVector* CreateVector(int _length)=0;

    SomeMatrix(int _rows,int _cols)
    {
        cols = _cols;
        rows = _rows;
        values = new IVector*[rows];
        for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            values[i] = CreateVector(cols);
        }
    }
};

class UsualMatrix:public SomeMatrix
{
public:
    IVector* CreateVector(int _length)
    {
        return new UsualVector(_length);
    }
};

class ThinMatrix:public SomeMatrix
{
public:
    IVector* CreateVector(int _length)
    {
        return new ThinVector(_length);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you paste the link error?

Comment: First a couple of things: Your code misses a couple of semicolons, and some indentation. And then there is no `raise` statement shown either. Please, if possible create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) to show us. And also of course **edit your question** to include it. And also the actual (unmodified and unedited) error messages may be good to have too.

Comment: You should also explain what exactly you mean by a "raise method".

Answer (score 1):

Calling a virtual function in a base class constructor to pull in information of a derived class is fundamentally wrong, there is no way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

In the `SomeMatrix` constructor the type of the object is `SomeMatrix` because you haven't started the derived constructor yet, so when you call the virtual `CreateVector` function the virtual dispatch invokes the one in the `SomeMatrix` base class, but you haven't provided a definition for that, so you get a linker error.

You could solve the linker error by providing a definition outside the class:

```
IVector* SomeMatrix::CreateVector(int _length)
{
  // ...
}
```

However that isn't going to do what you want. There is no way to call a derived class' virtual member function from a base class constructor (or base class destructor).